# Ember.js - Controller functions with observed properties don't execute when the function name changes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I’m using the new query params feature http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/ and trying to figure out an issue when using .property().

In the client side sorting example when I change the name of the methods sortProperties, or paged (I’ve added console output to each) they no longer execute when their observed property changes.  The name of the method shouldn’t matter right?

http://jsbin.com/ucanam/5069/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't rename `sortProperties`, it's property of [Ember.SortableMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.SortableMixin.html#property_sortProperties)

In your example computed property sets `sortProperties: [resultOfComutedProperty]` and if you'll rename sortProperties will no reasons to fire it.

`paged` is just computed property, don't forget to rename it in handlebars template and [all will work](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/5073/edit?html,js)

Comment: Thanks, that makes much more sense. I wasn't aware that the variable had to be used in the template and I'm not sure why if logic in the method depends on it [here](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/5083/edit).  I've switched to using observes, which is working without the variable being used in the template. Is this a good approach?

Comment: Result of computed property has to be used somewhere. 
For example: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/5084/edit?html,js
(result of `test2` is used in `pagedExt`)
Of course this way is over-complicated so using observers is good decision in such situation.
Article about computed properties, observers and bindings: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/what-do-i-use-when/